# Using Bootcamp Windows 10 on MBP finding very slow backup via C-Port to external SSD usb 3.1

Tags: backup, bootcamp, usb, ssd

Booting straight in to Windows 10 via Bootcamp on MacBook Pro 2019.
Have 4 USB-C ports.  Trying to back up to external SSD USB 3.1 C-port connection.
Incredibly slow IE 39byts/sec.   59Gb backup takes hours.  The SSD is formatted as exFAT 2Tb.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. USB 3.1 is *not* the same as USB-C. The former maxes out at about 5Mbp/s the latter, twice that. USB 3 uses the old-style rectangular USB connectors just like USB 1 & 2, where the USB-C is the newer smaller more rounded connector. So which is it USB 3 or USB C?

Comment: @SteveChambers: IMO your comment contains many inaccuracies. USB Type-C refers to a type of connector. USB 3.1 defines a type of communication and power delivery. USB 3.1 exists as Gen 1 (5 Gbps) and Gen 2 (10 Gps).

Comment: Sondela: What is the make/model of the external drive?